Can not overcome "Refused to load media from ... because it violates the following Content Security Policy" in Electron apps
I read Electron security documentation https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security
And made all points I found:

add to page special tag
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'">


open window with special setting
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    ...
    allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
    webSecurity: false
 })


add CSP to session
 session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders((details, callback) => {
      details.requestHeaders['Authorization'] = auth;
      callback({ cancel: false, 
        requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders,
        'Content-Security-Policy': ['default-src \'none\''] });
  });



however, browser refuse loading content from local cache
   Refused to load media from 'file:...mp4' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self' http://localhost:8989".

What I can do more than I done to overcome CSP (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)

You're trying to add another CSP with default-src 'none', but there is another existing CSP with media-src 'self' http://localhost:8989. Your content needs to pass all policies, so you will need to modify/remove the existing policy with media-src. This can be set in application code, webserver, proxy, load balancer etc, so you'll just need to locate it and then change it.

Hello, Halvor Sakshaug. Thank to join to discussion. I changed <meta tag to content="media-src 'self' http://localhost:8989" and received this error :    "Refused to load media from 'file:///C:/Users/Razen/AppData/Roaming/....mp4' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self' http://localhost:8989"."

And new trash message appears "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-/va6Jj/CavHKf07BatZWQ2vqoZ6k2ZMtWmnbF6vSc5w='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback." - what does mean that trash message and how to turn of this trash futures at all?

First it seems like you changed your policy to match the policy with the same media-src directive. At least one of your policies still block the content. The "thrash" message means that you have blocked execution of inline styles by "default-src 'self'" or my a restricted style-src directive.

I have search text media-src 'self' - this text NEVER faced on my project currently. I try to use your advice with "media-src 'self' http://localhost:8989" - error message not changed. This is my question - there are 3 potential points to delete restriction - one on meta tag in HTML, second point - Options that we use to open window  new BrowserWindow(windowOptions), and third point - in the session callback webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders((details, callback). This is my question - how is possible to delete any CSP restriction and allow page to play any my content. And I can not do that.

I try to use your advice, but unfortunately error message not changed. Therefore I have very simple question - this is absolute standard task - to delete ANY CSP restrictions. How to do this? One example please where CSP restriction successfully deleted.

  media-src 'self' file:" try using this approach  with updating main session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders((details, callback) => {     details.requestHeaders['Authorization'] = 'your-auth-token';     details.requestHeaders['Content-Security-Policy'] = [         "default-src 'none'; media-src 'self' file:"     ];     callback({          cancel: false,          requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders      }); });
